# How to Move up an XML Node in VB .NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Given an XML structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd">
  <Surfaces>
    <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
      <Definition surfType="TIN">
        <Pnts />
        <Faces />
      </Definition>
      <SourceData>
        <Boundaries>
          <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
            <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
          </Boundary>
        </Boundaries>
      </SourceData>
      <Units>
        <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
      </Units>
      <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy" />
      <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
        <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
      </Application>
    </Surface>
  </Surfaces>
</LandXML>
```

I want to move the `<Units>` node to the top just under `<LandXML>`, so it appears above the surfaces node node and I need to move the `<SourceData>` node under `<Surface>`.

Here's the final structure I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd">
  <Units>
    <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
  </Units>
  <Surfaces>
    <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
      <SourceData>
        <Boundaries>
          <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
            <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
          </Boundary>
        </Boundaries>
      </SourceData>
      <Definition surfType="TIN">
        <Pnts />
        <Faces />
      </Definition>
      <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy" />
      <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
        <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
      </Application>
    </Surface>
  </Surfaces>
</LandXML>
```

So far I have come up with this code:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(Xml_in)

Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0")

Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//LandXML", nsmgr)
Dim nodelist1 As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//LandXML")

For i As Integer = 0 To nodelist.Count - 1
    If (nodelist(i).HasChildNodes) Then
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = nodelist(i).ChildNodes
        For j As Integer = nodelist(i).ChildNodes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If (nodes(j).Name = "Units") Then
                msgbox("Found Units")
                Dim xn As XmlNode = nodes(j)
                nodelist(i).RemoveChild(nodes(j))
                nodelist1.InsertBefore(xn, nodelist1.FirstChild)
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next 
doc.Save(Xml_out)
MsgBox("Done")
```

However it will only output the original file and never displays the first message box. I think its not finding `<Units>` and I cant figure out how to get it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your original incomplete xml code, I think, according to the indentation, you meant to have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LandXML date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Surfaces>
    <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
      <Definition surfType="TIN">
        <Pnts></Pnts>
        <Faces></Faces>
      </Definition>
      <SourceData>
        <Boundaries>
          <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
            <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
          </Boundary>
        </Boundaries>
      </SourceData>
    </Surface>
  </Surfaces>
  <Units>
    <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
  </Units>
  <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy"></Project>
  <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
    <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
  </Application>
</LandXML>
```

Something like this, using XDocument, will work:

```
Sub MoveUnits(fileName As String)
    Dim file As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    Dim units As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}Units")
    Dim tempElement = file.Root.Elements(units)(0)
    tempElement.Remove()
    file.Root.AddFirst(tempElement)
    file.Save(fileName)
End Sub
```

The same procedure should be easy to follow for the other element you want to move.
This will result in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LandXML date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Units>
    <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
  </Units>
  <Surfaces>
    <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
      <Definition surfType="TIN">
        <Pnts></Pnts>
        <Faces></Faces>
      </Definition>
      <SourceData>
        <Boundaries>
          <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
            <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
          </Boundary>
        </Boundaries>
      </SourceData>
    </Surface>
  </Surfaces>
  <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy"></Project>
  <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
    <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
  </Application>
</LandXML>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That is exactly what I needed. However how would I move the source Data, Since there are multiple source Data Parts(I didnt include them in this XML to Shrink the size)

Comment: @Melona380 - It might be wiser to move the definitions element down to where you want it than looping through the sourcedata elements and moving them.

Comment: I thought about that too, but this is ment to convert the LandXml for different software.  It is very pickey about the order of certain elements. So source data must come before definition and after surface

Comment: If the xml code in my post is correct then moving definition instead of all the sourcedata will end up with sourcedata right after surface and right before definition.

Comment: Great, the only problem like I said is that there are multiple source data's and definitions that I took out to compress the code. So I need code That can find the source data that is for example the 3rd one down

Comment: Ok you didn't say before that there were multiple definitions. Are the defintion elements paired with the sourcedata elements and you just need the pairing reversed? Or is it inconsistent and you need all the sourcedata before all the definitions?  Either way I would suggest either an update to your question or even a new question with a better xml sample that is more reperesentative of what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think for your use case it should matter what order the child nodes are in.

It's semantically the same thing: There is *exactly one* `<SourceData>` child beneath `<Surface>`, it does not matter whether it appears as the first child or as the last. You can simply refer to it by name.

If you are currently building something that relies on `<SourceData>` being the first child, I strongly suggest you reconsider.

- your main problem: you can't have an empty namespace prefix in the `XmlNamespaceManager`<sup>(*)</sup>
- tip 1: you don't need to remove nodes that you want to move around in the document
- tip 2: VB.NET has type inference, you can drop explicit type declarations in most places

```vb
Shared Sub ProcessXml(Xml_in As String, Xml_out As String)
    Dim doc = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(Xml_in)

    Dim nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("land", "http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0")

    SetAsFirstChild(doc.SelectSingleNode("//land:Units", nsmgr), doc.DocumentElement)
    SetAsFirstChild(doc.SelectSingleNode("//land:SourceData", nsmgr))

    doc.Save(Xml_out)
End Sub

Shared Sub SetAsFirstChild(node As XmlNode, Optional parent As XmlNode = Nothing)
    If node Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If parent Is Nothing Then parent = node.ParentNode
    If parent Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    parent.InsertBefore(node, parent.FirstChild)
End Sub
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Technically, you can. However that does not affect XPath. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).